# RTD Server with c#

Tags: .net, excel

I am trying to build a c# app that gets data from a source. This data needs to be displayed in excel as well (on demand). Doing some research, I came across Excel Real Time Data Server (RTD Server). All resources show how to create a class project, Add a class and have it implement IRtdServer interface, register the assembly using regasm and then use excel to request data (=RTD("progId","","topic"))
     I have got all that working but what I want to do is being able to reflect changes in excel as the main source updates. For example, lets say that I'm showing data in excel that is also displayed on the grid to user. When user updates the data on grid, I want that update to be displayed in excel and when I close the application, excel gets informed that the server is no longer available.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can find more information...

[How do I create a real-time Excel automation add-in in C# using RtdServer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5397607/how-do-i-create-a-real-time-excel-automation-add-in-in-c-using-rtdserver)